# No login screen after upgrade to 15.10

Tags: nvidia, login, lightdm

The system is up and running, I can login with Ctrl-Alt-F1 or ssh -X from another computer. I can run graphical applications over ssh. The problem is that the login screen is gone. It's just a black screen. Have reinstalled graphics drivers (fglrx and nvidia-355), lightdm, gvm but same situation. How can I find out if my graphics driver is happy? No clues in dmesg. I used to run gnome classic before the upgrade. Nvidia GT640.

Comment: Why did you install fglrx for Nvidia?

Answer (score 1):

Well, sort of solved. Here's what I did:
1. reinstall nvidia-355 driver and let it run to completion. Takes a while. This made it possible to do "startx", so the login window was now visible, but I was in a login loop, couldn't get in.
2. Install Mate desktop. (not sure that was relevant)
3. Unistall Plymouth. This prompted a whole new packages to be installed, but I said yes. A script asked if I wanted to use gdm, lightdm or something new called ssdm. I chose ssdm.
Finally! a new login screen allowed me to select a number of desktop systems, such as gnome, plasma, metacity, failsafe... and mate. If I choose mate (the last installed) I can login (YES!) but for all other choices I end up in the loop. Hope this helps someone.